# Intellij IDEA Project view doesn't show structure as it did before.

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My directory structure in the Project seems to have disappeared. The first picture is the "bad".  I recently upgraded to 12.1 and the vim emulator at about the same time.  I don't know if I missed a dialog that reset something?  I can't figure out how to get it back like the second picture.
I've tried to re-import the project but it has not helped.  I keep the project on Dropbox and have another PC where I have not reloaded project.  Is there a way to get my view from that machine?

### [image: Bad]

The picture is the "good" and how I want it to look.
[image: Good]

Comment: Double check your project/module configuration in the [project structure](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/accessing-project-structure.html) settings. Your module needs to have content roots and source roots defined properly. Your "good" screenshot is also wrong as source roots are not defined.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I've come across this problem a few times myself.  What happened is that intellij lost the module in my project settings.  Here's my steps to fix it:

File -> Project Structure -> Click on modules (notice empty list) ->
Click on '+' -> Click on import module -> Find existing myProj.iml

Comment: What if there is no myProj.iml?

Comment: do you know why does it happen? is there any reported bug for which I could vote regarding this?

Comment: This answer is 6 years old and the problem still exists in IntelliJ. For projects with many modules, it can be a real pain reconstructing them after each time this occurs. I suggest that once you reconstruct the modules, back up the .idea folder so you can easily restore it next time.

Comment: @PlsWork in the latest versions of InteliJ it's enough to open directory even if there's no .iml file

Comment: This didn't have any effect for me (maybe v2023 has changed a bit). Simple current solution is below: delete the hidden .idea folder. There is nothing vital in there, the IDE just re-generates it.

Answer (score 4):

I also have quite a few IntelliJ projects and also git folders of text files.  I found IntelliJ does not always reconstruct the .idea files correctly.  However the following methods work for me.

Open IntelliJ in the top folder where there is no .idea folder.  Often IntelliJ will just construct a new .idea folder and works.

Copy an .idea folder from a similar project and modify to fit.  The xml files in the .idea are reasonable to modify.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working on a software development project where you are using Maven, Gradle, Flash Builder etc., the below mentioned steps should restore the project structure:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (or) File>>Project Structure
2. Select 'Modules' in 'Project Settings'
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> (or) Select '+' to add a new module
4. Select 'Import Module'
5. Select the folder you want to import the module from(Generally the parent folder)
6. Select 'Import module from external model' and the corresponding external model

This resets your project structure.

Answer (score 3):

Open IntelliJ in the root project level works for me.

I have a mixed project folder tree like the following:

```
git_root
- proj_android
- proj_ios
- proj_react
  - lib
  - src
```

My problem is that when I open IntelliJ on my proj_react folder, I could not see my src folder or lib folder.  (My proj_react is one level down from my git_root.)

Then I open IntelliJ on git_root, I could see everything.  The problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can sometimes rescue projects like these by going and resetting their content root in the module settings. Or even recreate the module as another answer suggests.

This is something that would happen to me if I opened an IntelliJ project in PhPStorm, then tried to open it in IntelliJ again.

However as was mentioned the project format changed recently, so you should use the same version of intelliJ to work on your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a content root for a project module that intersects with another content root, then this problem will occur.  For example:

```
Project A (content root)
    - source for A
    - module B (content root)
      - source for B
```

If you have a project that has a source root for "Project A" and you add a source root for "module B" you will end up with missing structure, such as your first picture.  This happens because the content root for module B is within project A structure.

This worked at one time, as I have the setup above with multiple modules.  When I upgraded to 12.1.6 this stopped working.  If you have overlapping source roots you will see this problem.

I'm using 12.1.6 on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

*On Mac:*

- Preferences
- search for Project Structure or go directly to:
- Project: Your_Project_Name / Project Structure
- Mark all as Sources (mine was marked as "Excluded")

Answer (score 0):

What did you update from? If you did a few major versions update, intellij really changed how their projects are laid out. You probably need to edit the projuct structure and add a new java module.

Comment: I think the old version was 12.01 or something similar.  I've been updating each time the notice pops up that there is a new version, so whatever the previous version was.
EDIT: Looking on the Intellij www site I suspect the old version was 12.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

This is the quick fix that i have done:

1. Close the IDE and open the project folder in file manager
2. Delete the .idea folder and reopen the project in IDE.

To view the hidden folder and files:

Open the folder and press cntrl+H (in linux), And in windows Go to folder options and check `view hidden files` option.

Comment: If you do this, all of your files will stop appearing in IDEA.

Comment: No, it won't happen. It's like opening a fresh project folder via IDE. Maybe you have misunderstood my comment.

Comment: I've upvoted this from -1 to 0, as ALL the solutions above do not work for me. The project compiled and ran as a Maven project, but the IDE wasn't showing the files. I deleted the hidden .idea folder and opened the project and all is well again. The folder just contains various config files and what files you had open at the time, nothing important.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is 8 years old and the problem still exists in IntelliJ. For projects with many modules, it can be a real pain reconstructing them after each time this occurs. I suggest that once you reconstruct the modules, back up the .idea folder so you can easily restore it next time

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom left corner of IntellIJ you'll find an icon, using which you can fetch project structure, etc..,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).